# How to set up environment on bash script to run command on loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to run a command (called *Purify*) multiple times on terminal before I can get convergence by reusing a solution previously solved by the command. Before doing that, I have to set up the environment which I have an alias in my bashrc as:

```
`alias `fil30='source $HOME/.../Bin/bin/Source.bash'
```

This process is working as intended. To make life simpler, I thought of running the command on loop, by sourcing the source.bash file in a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.../Bin/bin/Source.bash
while true; do
    Purify -s Output/waterRun_t
done
```

However, I am still running into the error below:

```
Purify: command not found
```

I think the looping part is fine, just that *Purify* command is not found. How do I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Is `Purify` the name of an alias or the name of an executable?

Comment: Is `Purify` itself an alias? It might be defined by `Source.bash`, but alias expansion is turned off by default in non-interactive shells. Try adding `shopt -s expand_aliases` to the script.

Comment: ...or turn `Purify` into a function if it is currently an alias.

Comment: What output this command show?
`type Purify`

Comment: Are the backticks around your `alias ` command intentional? Also, could you show the contents of your `Source.bash`?

Comment: yes, `Purify` is an alias command. and the suggestion by @chepner fixed the problem! Thanks!